# Transfer ownership of a derived class unique_ptr to its abstract base class unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I want to transfer ownership of a derived class unique_ptr to its abstract base class unique_ptr in a polymorphic situation. How to go about?

```
class Fruit {
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class Apple: public Fruit {
public:
    string name;
    virtual  void print()  { cout << " Apple name is " << name << endl; }
    Apple(string name): name(name) {}
};


int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Apple> apple = make_unique<Apple>("Rose");
    unique_ptr<Fruit> fruit = dynamic_cast<unique_ptr<Fruit>>(apple); // don't work
    // want to transfer ownership of apple to fruit

    unique_ptr<Apple> new_apple = dynamic_cast<unique_ptr<Apple>>(fruit); // get back the ownership to the new apple
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unique_ptr<Fruit> fruit = make_unique<Apple>("Rose");` should work

Comment: Though its easy in raw pointer, shuttling from derived to base class and vice versa is bit of an issue using the smart pointer.

Comment: @JohnFilleau `Fruit` needs a virtual destructor to permit `Apple` to be destroyed from a base class pointer.

Comment: @Raymond So it does. One should be declaring a virtual destructor on the base class if one wants to use polymorphism, correct?

Comment: @JohnFilleau A virtual destructor is not required for polymorphism. It is needed if a derived class is deleted via a pointer to a base class.

Comment: @Raymond seems like a best practice to just do it whenever you're doing polymorphism then, no? Treat every gun like it's loaded. Treat every polymorphic base class like one of its derived classes would be deleted through it. Etc. etc.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Sounds interesting. After declaration the virtual destructor, how to convert drviedm to based and back? Please anwser I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transfer ownership of a derived class managed by a derived class `unique_ptr` to a base class `unique_ptr`, you can (and should) use move semantics.

```
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> foo = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bar = std::move(foo);
```

To return ownership to a derived `unique_ptr`, you need to get a little messier:

```
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> foo = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bar = std::move(foo);

    std::unique_ptr<Derived> biz(static_cast<Derived*>(bar.release()));
```

If you're unsure of the actual type of the pointer, then a dynamic cast can be used to check that it's correct. Note that we use `std::unique_ptr<Base>::get()` in the conditional, since we're not sure we want to release ownership yet. If this passes, then we can call `std::unique_ptr<Base>::release()`.

```
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> foo = std::make_unique<Derived>();
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bar = std::move(foo);

    // dynamic cast if we're unsure that it is castable
    if (dynamic_cast<Derived*>(bar.get())) {
        foo.reset(static_cast<Derived*>(bar.release()));
    }
```

[see it in action](https://godbolt.org/z/9dGT11T9W)

Comment: Option 2 works like charm. I will be using it frequently, is it the optimum way? Anyways thanks.

Comment: @ark The optimum way is to not cast back and forth at all. Transferring ownership between unique pointers really should only be done when the object that owns the resource is destroyed or moved. If you're attempting to use polymorphism, then you don't need to hold the resource as the derived class. If a function needs a base pointer you can just `.get()` on the derived unique pointer without swapping ownership. We would need to see your actual use case to help you figure out the correct way to do whatever you're trying.

Answer (score 1):

try move assignment

```
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Apple> apple = make_unique<Apple>("Rose");
    unique_ptr<Fruit> fruit = std::move(apple);
    fruit->print();
    // want to transfer ownership of apple to fruit
    return 0;
}
```