# Dynamic cast a pointer to a child class unique pointer to pointer of parent class unique pointer

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, dynamic-cast

I have a `Parent` and `Child` class and would like to dynamic cast a pointer to a `std::unique_ptr<Child>` into a pointer to a `std::unique_ptr<Parent>` has shown in the code below. However when trying to do so I get the compilation error

```bash
error: 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Child, std::__1::default_delete<Child> >' is not polymorphic
```

If instead I do not use the `dynamic_cast` (see the commented line in the code below) it works.
I would like to understand if it would be possible to use the `dynamic_cast`, and if yes what should I modify for it to work

Many thanks in advance for your help.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> 

class Parent{
  public:
    Parent(){
    }
    virtual ~Parent(){
      std::cout << "Deleter of Parent class" << std::endl; 
    }
};

class Child: public Parent {
  public:
    Child(){
    }
    virtual ~Child(){
      std::cout << "Deleter of Child class" << std::endl; 
    }
};

int main(){
  std::unique_ptr<Child> myUniquePtr = std::make_unique<Child>();
  std::unique_ptr<Parent>* ptrToUniquePtr = dynamic_cast<std::unique_ptr<Parent>*>( &myUniquePtr ); // Does not work 
  // std::unique_ptr<Parent>* ptrToUniquePtr = (std::unique_ptr<Parent>*) ( &myUniquePtr ); // Works 
  
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `dynamic_cast` doesn't work this way. But you can certainly write a function that internally uses `dynamic_cast` on underlying raw pointers. You have to carefully think through the design of this function - recall that it wouldn't make sense to end up with two instances of `unique_ptr` both managing the same object. If the "cast" succeeds, the ownership would have to be transferred from one pointer to the other.

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr<Parent> myUniquePtr = std::make_unique<Child>();` like you would do with normal polymorphic classes (i.e. `Parent* p = new Child;`)

Comment: As for the problem, `std::unique_ptr<Child>*` and `std::unique_ptr<Parent>*` are just two different and unrelated types.

Comment: What's the point of `dynamic_cast` here though? You could just do `std::unique_ptr<Parent> parentPtr = std::move(childPtr);`. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/); what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik, maybe I should have specified better what I want to achieve.
I have simplified my issue and provided a minimal reproducer but so basically  
my primary goal would be to store into a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent>*>` object some `std::unique_ptr<T>* ` with `T` different classes inheriting from the `Parent` class. Like I am not interested by the `std::unique_ptr<T>` to `std::unique_ptr<Parent>` conversion. 
What I would need is find the way to convert a `std::unique_ptr<T>* ` into a `std::unique_ptr<Parent>* ` hence the dynamic cast try

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<Parent>` are distinct unrelated classes, even if `T` is related to `Parent`; neither is derived from the other. You can't obtain `std::unique_ptr<Parent>*` from `std::unique_ptr<T>`. In order to have `std::unique_ptr<Parent>*`, you first need `std::unique_ptr<Parent>` for it to point to; and `std::unique_ptr<T>` ain't that.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks a lot for your explanation! 
So the line 
```std::unique_ptr<Parent>* ptrToUniquePtr = (std::unique_ptr<Parent>*) ( &myUniquePtr );```  that seems to work is indeed wrong ?

Comment: Well, with the C-style cast you can convert anything to anything else, whether or not it makes sense. I mean, `int x = 42; std::string* ps = (std::string*)(&x)` compiles, too; but of course trying to use `ps` afterwards would end in tears, as there isn't an actual `std::string` object anywhere in this picture.

Comment: Okay yes right thanks a lot again for all your explanation I was not sure about if what I wanted to "achieve" was correct or no and it appears it is not now it makes sense to me thanks to you!

Comment: Having a pointer to a unique pointer is quite a strange thing to want to do. If you want to store a non-owning copy of the pointer then just use a raw pointer, if it's an owning copy that you want then use a `shared_ptr`

Comment: Also very good duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70457355/transfer-ownership-of-a-derived-class-unique-ptr-to-its-abstract-base-class-uniq (Transfer ownership of a derived class unique_ptr to its abstract base class unique_ptr)

Comment: Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484183/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-stdunique-ptr-while-pushing-into-stdvector (What is the correct usage of std::unique_ptr while pushing into std::vector). Do not store/use pointer to unique_ptr, that is like forging an unique official document to get around limitations. You have a reason (ownership and automatic resource management) to use unique_ptr in the first place.